# Creating a dynamic union select in C# Method

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

Can someone improve on my method for creating union select views from 2 databases located within the same server in C#, here is the code for the method:

```
public override DataSet GetDynamicReportData(string strSQL) {

            var sbSQL = new StringBuilder(strSQL);
            var finalQueryStr = new StringBuilder(strSQL);

            sbSQL.Replace("SELECT DISTINCT ", "");

            var iamNEAS3 =
                new StringBuilder(" UNION SELECT DISTINCT ");

            var queryColumns = sbSQL.ToString().Split(',');

            for (var i = 0; i <= queryColumns.Length - 1; i++) {

                iamNEAS3.Append(queryColumns[i]);

                if (i < queryColumns.Length - 1) {
                    iamNEAS3.Append(", ");
                } else if (i == queryColumns.Length - 1) {

                    var appendMagic =
                        queryColumns[i].Replace(
                            "From [dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationsFiles]",
                            "FROM [project_phoenix].[dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationFiles]")

                    iamNEAS3.Append(appendMagic);

                    // Systematic removal; thank you!
                    iamNEAS3.Replace(queryColumns[i], "");
                }
            }

            finalQueryStr.Append(iamNEAS3);

            return DALDynamicReport.GetData(finalQueryStr.ToString());
        }
```

Now it receives a string parameter where

```
strSQL = "Select Distinct [Row1], [Row2], [Row3], [Row4] From [project_mongoose].[dbo].[vw_Classified_ApplicationsFiles] where [Row2] <= 200".
```

I know my programming skills are limited, but is there a way to not code this by hand like I did?

Comment: what you need to create the dynamic rows selection anyway?? create a proc and use it directly which we lot easier and manageable.

Comment: Good idea Dirty one, but let assume an environment where my data source is views only and I have no to access to backend actual databases whatsoever

Comment: why you are not creating the query string directly here?

Comment: Well, the rows being selected are dynamically created by another system, so the method can not know exactly what is created before receiving strSQL parameter, that's why I recreate the row for the union select... I hope I'm clear <ComplexCodeByHand>

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Don't do this. Don't even think this way. Can you imagine assembling your application code like this, fragments floating around in string literals, a part of it sucked in from some other place, a bit added at the last minute, a bit of Replace(), then execute to see what gets spat out, and if it runs? nightmare

I'm sure if you look hard at the requirement, you can come up with a better way.

Comment: That's what I feared, its a daisy chain